# Eclipse IDE java - Run the previous program

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i run the Factnumber.java program

But it running program is previous program Fibonacci.java ( it was the previous  program)

it run again and again same program

i want to fix that error or any other option to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the **Launch Operation** part of your **Launching** preference page. This hasn't been the default behavior for a very long time, so if you are not using the 2023-06 release, please update to it.